# What is the difference between an Integrator and a Low pass filter?

Tags: signal-processing, xcos

I am working on a Digital Down converter (DDC) in xcos. I need to know whether an integrator and a LPF are same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, and hence is off-topic for StackOverflow. Try http://dsp.stackexchange.com the next time!

Comment: Also, no, they are not. Basic research on both terms would've showed that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different kinds of low-pass filters.

An integrator is one kind of low pass filter.  It's a "filter", because it is linear and time-invariant (LTI), and it is "low pass" because its low-frequency response is bigger than its high-frequency response.

But perfect integrators are not typically used by themselves (in DSP) for any tasks that you would call "low-pass filtering".  They are unstable at DC, and their response is far from optimal for filtering jobs.  Certainly a digital down-converter requires a much better, purpose-designed, low-pass anti-aliasing filter.

But the *electronic* circuits called "integrators" are *imperfect* integrators.  These kinds of circuits are easy to construct, and with different component values can actually be useful for filtering.  They can still be referred to as "integrators" in that case.